# How to differentiate between manually installed packages and dependencies on linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, apt

I am a noob in linux and right now I am using a raspberry pi with raspbian to learn about it. I am trying the commands to install and uninstall packages (apt) but i have the following doubt.

Is there a way to differentiate between packages that I have installed and packages that were automatically installed because they are dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't realize there were those sites. I'll post there from now on. Thanks for the info.

Comment: No need to apologize. It happens all the time. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are very good sites for these types of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to differentiate between packages that I have installed and packages that were automatically installed because they are dependencies?

Probably not, and that should not matter. Suppose you have some package `foo` that has been installed as a dependency for `bar`. A few days latter, you might want to install `foo` (and since it is already installed, nothing will happen).

Comment: I can see your point. Didn't think about that. Now I can see how pointless the question was. Thank you so much.